# breakpoint (gem) not found or unreadable

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, breakpoint-sass

I’m using breakpoint within a [serve](https://github.com/jlong/serve) project. After adding `require 'breakpoint'` to my './config.ru' and `@import 'breakpoint'` to my stylesheets, breakpoint works well while running serve (which I actually run via [Pow](http://pow.cx/)).

However, when using `serve export` to export the site to static HTML/CSS/JS files within a predetermined folder, I get the following error in my stylesheets:

```
/*
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
          Load paths:
            /Users/agarzola/git/devdev-splash/stylesheets
            /Users/agarzola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.16/stylesheets
            Compass::SpriteImporter
    on line 5 of ./stylesheets/screen.sass

1: /Users/agarzola/git/devdev-splash/stylesheets/screen.sass

Backtrace:
./stylesheets/screen.sass:5
[…]
*/
```

I’ve been poking around the serve gem itself and found that export simply runs `compass compile -c '#{@input}/compass.config' '#{@input}'` to compile stylesheets before copying them to the destination folder. I had also learned some time ago that the export feature in serve does not yet use `config.ru` (as it should), and I haven’t been able to figure out where exactly I need to tell compass to use the installed breakpoint gem.

So I tried running `compass compile -c ./compass.config` and `compass watch -c ./compass.config`, both of which return a similar error:

```
error stylesheets/screen.sass (Line 5 of screen.sass: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
Load paths:
  /Users/agarzola/git/devdev-splash/stylesheets
  /Users/agarzola/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.16/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter)
```

I created [an issue on the serve project](https://github.com/jlong/serve/issues/113), but I’m hoping someone here can share some much needed insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I have to uninstall the theme and reinstall because for some reason the gems were not being seem. [Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180811/omega-compass-library-error/22201947#22201947)

After I uninstalled the theme, I ran install bundle and then checked rvm requirements. Then I reinstalled the theme and subtheme. I do not use serve however this could be similar enough that it might work. I did not find anything that helped other then that.