# Omega Compass Library error

Tags: ruby, drupal, rvm, compass-sass

I am going through the motions to understanding the Omega 4 Theme in drupal. I did the sub-theme through drush and I have rvm, ruby and I believe all the gems installed.

I should add that I have rgbapng & compass installed. I am not familiar with the @global though...

However when I go to the site I see this error:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: rpbapng.
Load paths:
/Library/Webserver/Documents/tpw/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/sass
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
Compass::SpriteImporter
on line 1 of     /Library/Webserver/Documents/tpw/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/sass/omega.development.scss

1: //Library/Webserver/Documents/tpw/sites/all/themes/omega/omega/sass/omega.development.scss
```

I have compass installed. It works for another site as well.
I am not sure what to check, test or reinstall. Does someone have experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Weird enough as this was, I had to uninstall all parts of omega, the subtheme and reboot. I then wen back into terminal to make sure that I installed bundle and checked for rvm requirements. Then I re-installed omega and re-ran the subtheme through terminal. Cleared cache and everything seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience after updating Omega in a dev directory, it seemed to have changed the gem list, and all hell broke loose.

I backed up my subtheme, the disabled my subtheme and omega, then deleted both from the server.  I downloaded the same version of omega that I was originally using, followed the instructions for creating a subtheme, used the same name and options for my subtheme and omega-guard started working with no errors.

I was then able to salvage my sass files and the rest of my subtheme.  Be careful to only restore the Drupal specific portions of the subtheme, not the config.rb, Gemfile, etc.  Not sure if this will break anything, but at this time of day, I am not taking chances.

A quick note, I did not need to reboot.